# minionpro: v and \nu in math mode

Tags: fonts, typography

I have noticed that with *Minion Pro* font `v` and `\nu` are indistinguishable.

Does anyone know a decent workaround to this?

Somewhere in the web it was suggested to use `\upsilon` as a substitute for `v`.
It's a bit irritating, however: You lose `\upsilon` and `w` and `v` will look too different.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: J. This is really a font issue: that is the design of the font. The work-around is to pick a different font!

Comment: @Joseph Wright: You are right. However, I wouldn't like to let go of Minion completely. I'm looking for (1) a way to replace v and w (or \nu) with something else and (2) a good choice of "something else". Here the point (2) is more important for me. (Point (1) is probably relatively easy.)

Comment: J. My point is that this is really not a TeX question, it's about typography. Quite apart from that, fonts are designed 'as a whole'. If the font you choose has poor glyphs for your use case, this suggests it's the wrong font for the job in hand.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Yes, this is not a TeX question. I was however under impression that this might still be an acceptable question for this site. (Judging from previous questions like this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/what-best-combination-of-fonts-for-serif-sans-and-mono-do-you-recommend ) Sorry if I was wrong!

Comment: Perhaps it would suffice to import `\nu` from Computer Modern. See the middle two lines of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435722/98394.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to have been solved by Johannes Küster in his MnMath. See for example [this presentation by him](http://www.typoma.com/publ/20041002-atypi.pdf#page=11) on page 11, where he shows a redesigned math italic "v" and "w".

However MnMath is *not* cheap (around 700€ for the complete set) compared to *free* for MnSymbol.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how hard would it be to add (and design) alternative v and w for MnSymbol. (Using them could be optional for the user.)

Comment: If you can get those glyphs designed, then adding them as optional math symbols should be relatively easy to do (see for example how the MinionPro package implements the [openg] option to switch to open g for mathmode).