# Aligning \overline to “italics” font but starting with upshape

Tags: math-mode, italic, italic-correction

I want to write an X with a bar on top. The X should be upright, but in headings it should be italics. The bar should be in the correct position. So my question is a variant of [Aligning \overline to "italics" font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95014/aligning-overline-to-italics-font). I started to play with [jfbu's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95079/18561) but cannot get the original upshape position to work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\newbox\usefulbox

\makeatletter
\def\getslant #1{\strip@pt\fontdimen1 #1}

\def\skoverline #1{\mathchoice
 {{\setbox\usefulbox=\hbox{$\m@th\displaystyle #1$}%
    \dimen@ \getslant\the\textfont\symletters \ht\usefulbox
    \divide\dimen@ \tw@ 
    \kern\dimen@ 
    \overline{\kern-\dimen@ \box\usefulbox\kern\dimen@ }\kern-\dimen@ }}
 {{\setbox\usefulbox=\hbox{$\m@th\textstyle #1$}%
    \dimen@ \getslant\the\textfont\symletters \ht\usefulbox
    \divide\dimen@ \tw@ 
    \kern\dimen@ 
    \overline{\kern-\dimen@ \box\usefulbox\kern\dimen@ }\kern-\dimen@ }}
 {{\setbox\usefulbox=\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle #1$}%
    \dimen@ \getslant\the\scriptfont\symletters \ht\usefulbox
    \divide\dimen@ \tw@ 
    \kern\dimen@ 
    \overline{\kern-\dimen@ \box\usefulbox\kern\dimen@ }\kern-\dimen@ }}
 {{\setbox\usefulbox=\hbox{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle #1$}%
    \dimen@ \getslant\the\scriptscriptfont\symletters \ht\usefulbox
    \divide\dimen@ \tw@ 
    \kern\dimen@ 
    \overline{\kern-\dimen@ \box\usefulbox\kern\dimen@ }\kern-\dimen@ }}%
 {}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\xbar}{$\skoverline{X}$\xspace}
\newcommand{\xbarup}{\mbox{$\overline{\mbox{X}}$}\xspace}

\newcommand{\xbarupsk}{\mbox{$\skoverline{\mbox{X}}$}\xspace}


\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\xbar-Theory
\emph{\xbar-Theory} (correct)

\xbarup-Theory (correct)
\emph{\xbarup-Theory}

\xbarupsk-Theory
\emph{\xbarupsk-Theory}





\end{document}
```

Comment: the way you're using it, the X with overbar is text, not math.  unfortunately, the usual text accent `\=` isn't long enough.  what is needed is a diacritic equivalent to unicode U+0305.  this may be available in the `xits` fonts.

Comment: Hm, but then the X may be different from my X, which is Linux Libertine.

Comment: i wasn't suggesting to use another font entirely.  it should be potentially possible to access just one or a few characters from an "extra" font, similarly to what is done here (although this example is for a math symbol): [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Comment: Yes, but the X would be different.

Comment: If there was a way to detect whether I am in `\emph` or not, I could use either of the macros.