# Distinguish between $v$ and $\nu$

Tags: math-mode

I'm writing a manuscript (100 page) and I used many times the symbols `$v$` and `$\nu$` in mathematical mode. For example my equations have the form:

```
$\frac{u+v}{\nu}=0$ and the pdf gives the following:
```

[image: outcome]

Unfortunately, after compiling, the two symbols `$v$` and `$\nu$` are very similar and it is very difficult to distinguish them.

Please can you help me to overcome this problem knowing that I can't change the symbol `$v$` in 100 pages

Comment: They seem distinguishable [image-click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrOaP.png) with the Computer Modern fonts. Can you tell something more about your setup?

Comment: if using `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` there is a specific option `varvw` to help alleviate this problem.

Comment: @egreg Im trying to put an image to what I obtained when I write $\frac{u+v}{\nu}$

Comment: @AndrewSwann I use amstext

Comment: Please provide a MWE so we can see what class and packages you are using.

Comment: @lblb Infact I use many many packages and I dont know if I can put all of them. for example: \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[english]{babel}   
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}          
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}    
\usepackage{multicol}   
\usepackage{graphics}     
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}     
\usepackage{latexsym}     
\usepackage{setspace}    
\usepackage{algorithm}   \usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{makeidx}    
\usepackage{vmargin}

Comment: @A H: A [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is one that produces your problem with only the relevant packages, so you wouldn't need most of the packages you listed. Creating a MWE is itself some work, but greatly appreciated for people tackling a question.

Comment: @AH All the packages you listed in the previous comment don't generate your problem, click on the link of lblb's comment to know how to create a minimal working example and then edit your question and add it, please!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 16):

Judging from the image you probably have

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

in your document.

Replace it with

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}
```

and the output of

```
\[
\frac{u+v}{\nu}
\]
```

will be, with no other change to your document,

[image]

Comment: I used this package \usepackage{mathrsfs}

Comment: @AH That's completely irrelevant. What document class are you using?

Comment: @egred \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

Comment: @AH Please, add a small example to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using Computer Modern for `v` and `\nu`.

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathord}{CMletters}{23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathord}{CMletters}{`v}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could retain the standard newtxmath `v`, which is readily distinguishable from the Computer Modern `\nu`, in order to avoid introducing confusion between `v` and `\upsilon`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, but since I did not want to make any changes (I wasnt sure if the proposed solutions would change anything in a finalised document, such as line-breaks, any slight changes of spacing, etc.), i preferred the following solution that solves the problem by adding a single line ("AtBeginDocument..."):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`v=\varv}

\begin{document}

A `v' in math: $v$

A `nu' in math: $\nu$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code follows along the lines of Gavin R. Putland's comment on Syrtis Major's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435722/295947), but it makes the Computer Modern `\nu` a bit thicker, so it fits in better with a Times font.  It also has a bold version, patterned on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684049/295947). (To explain the `'027` of the fifth line, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130619/295947).)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMMforNu}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{CMMforNu}{bold}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nuCM}{\mathord}{CMMforNu}{'027}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\def\nu{\mathord{\contourlength{0.0043em}\contour{black}{$\nuCM$}}}
\begin{document}
\[ \frac{u+v}{\nuCM \nu \boldmath\nu} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: CM nu thickened]

I got the idea of using the `contour` package in this way from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27845/295947) and the comment on it by diabonas.  As an alternative to using the `contour` package for making the symbol darker, the `pdfrender` package could be used, as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405446/295947) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383798/295947).

If you want the `v` to look as in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364107/295947), change the second line of my code to

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}
```

and the result is

[image: CM nu thickened with alternative v]

For discussions of non-Computer Modern versions of `\nu` and how to distinguish them from `v`, see the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/508231/295947).