# Bold \checkmark

Tags: symbols, amsmath, bold, pifont, bbding

Is there any way to make `amsmath`'s `\checkmark` symbol boldface?

I am aware that there are other symbols such as `bbding`'s `\CheckmarkBold` or `pifont`'s `\ding{52}` that do yield something similar to the desired result, but the slant of those checkmarks is very different from that of `\checkmark` and the output looks very odd, especially when you need to combine both regular and bold checkmarks in the same paragraph.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the outline of the checkmark glyph is not only filled but stroked with a line width, then the symbol becomes bolder. The following example uses this method with the help of package `pdfrender`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\newcommand*{\boldcheckmark}{%
  \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth=.5pt, % half of the line width is outside the normal glyph
  }{\checkmark}%
}
\begin{document}
  $\checkmark$ $\boldcheckmark$
\end{document}
```

The result is a smooth bold character:

> [image: Result]

Comment: (+1), so farI was no aware for this possibilities! thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no bold checkmark provided by the fonts, there is only the last ressort of *Poor man's bold* provided by the package `amsbsy`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\errorcontextlines=10
\begin{document}
$\checkmark$ $\pmb{\checkmark}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hadn't thought about using a _pmb_ solution, but this seems to be a more than acceptable compromise, thanks!