# Greek symbol fonts in latex

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, greek, newtxmath

I'm an engineering student currently working on the thesis. I'm using the math font package `newtxmath`, which generates the greek letter `\nu` as:

[image]

while the symbol font I want is:

[image]

I have been trying so hard to find a specific math font which may generate the latter symbol, but I couldn't find one yet. It will be much appreciated if anyone can give me an idea on this. Many thanks in advance!

Edit1:
The code I used for the former example is:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
$\nu$
\end{document}
```

Edit2: Thanks for the comments and answers! I'm sorry but I cannot leave comments to each comment and answer due to lack of reputations now.
@Ralf Stubner, I just ran pdffonts and the result is attached here (The problem is that I'm not sure which one is the one.. and do we have Times-Roman in latex other than newtxmath & newtxtest? It's curious..):
[image]

Edit3: @Cicada, thanks! I think it matches the pdf! Though I have one more thing to ask. I tried your code, but it gave me an error message saying that I need to use LuaTex. Is there any way to get the same result using pdflatex? Thanks in a dvance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a minimal working example regarding what you have tried starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you have a PDF file that uses that nu? Then you could inspect the used fonts via your viewer or the `pdffonts` program.

Answer (score 8):

First find the font.

[image: nu maths]

Then, if it is Unicode (U+1D708 is mathematical small nu, i.e. italic), use `unicode-math` to activate it with `setmathfont{}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Math}
\begin{document}
\Huge
$\nu$
\end{document}
```

STIX Math is a partial match (for the pointy bit), Latin Modern Math for the angle of the main bar.

=====

It's an italic ordinary nu (U+03BD), in STIX (or XITS).

[image: nu from STIX]

Italic ordinary lowercase Greek being used for symbols. Does that match your PDF?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand\SampleText{\textit{\symbol{"03BD}}}%\symbol{"1D708}}
\newfontfamily\frc{STIX}% Math}
\newfontfamily\fre{XITS}% Math}
\newcommand\printther[2]{{#1\Huge\SampleText} -- #2}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printther{\frc}{STIX}

\printther{\fre}{XITS}
\end{multicols}
{\frc \SampleText}
{\fre \SampleText}
\end{document}
```

=====

My answer is: I recommend using unicode, since that would be the standard nowadays. (How was the source PDF produced, for example - the one with the desired character shape?)

All the rest that follows is more of a minor exploratory footnote than substantive, and not intended as part of my actual answer.

There will be ways to get a character in without using xelatex or lualatex and direct unicode, but I don't know the old-style font encodings. Redefining the `\nu` macro is another possibility. Or an SE question has answered this already, perhaps.  It depends on your context: do you need just one character changed, or a whole font family? And pdflatex only? Sounds like it should be a separate question, to get the best results the quickest.

Expanding on the comments: `\usepackage{stix}` in pdflatex produces this:

[image: nu stix pdf]

====

Expanding still further, there's a way to access glyphs in old-style fonts (probably multiple ways actually, I would expect).

For pdflatex, there is an italic nu sitting in position x17 in the `stix-mathit` `tfm` font metric file, and a more cursive one in the same position in the `stix2-mathit` `tfm`.

To use them in math mode, use the `\text` command from the `amsmath` package.

[image: tfm nu]

You can adjust the size manually.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\font\myfont = "stix-mathit" at 36pt
\font\myfontb = "stix2-mathit" at 36pt
\font\myfontc = "stix-mathit" at 12pt
\newcommand\mynu{\text{\myfontc\char"17}}
\begin{document}
\myfont\char"17
\myfontb\char"17

$\text{\myfontc\char"17} = f^{2}$

$\mynu = f^{2}$

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, no packages at all gives this:

[image: plain nu]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\Huge $\nu$
\end{document}
```

I still recommend unicode, though.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine. The symbol is STIX or XITS. I am very glad to remove my answer and thank you very much the users that have voted positively to me. I am the first that have give you +1 :-).

Comment: In `unicode-math`, you should use XITS Math instead of STIX Math. It’s a fork that fixes a number of bugs. There’s also a `stix` package for PDFLaTeX.

Comment: @John, I didn't see your answer. (I hadn't refreshed the page before clicking edit, as I recall.) What do you recommend?

Comment: @John, Yes. Done! More logical and usable that way,

Answer (score 5):

The `newtxmath` package includes several options for changing the math font, e.g., to use the `STIX2` fonts, `libertine` fonts, `garamondx` fonts, etc. without giving up the many other nice features of the `newtx` bundle.  There is also an option `varvw` (and `varg`) that will load versions of v and w (and also y and g) that are more distinctive, so as to avoid confusion with nu, e.g.

This example isn't a match to your requested glyph, but it may give a sense of the possibilities without having to change your font set.

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[varg,stix2]{newtxmath}
%\usepackage[varg]{newtxmath}
%\usepackage[varg,libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[ 
\nu \textrm { is not } v \qquad \int_0^\delta \nu \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}\, dy
\]

\end{document}
```

`newtx` with `varg`:
[image]

`newtx` with `varg` and `stix2`:
[image]

`newtx` with `varg` and `libertine`:
[image]

EDIT -- Cicada has made the good suggestion to try the `newtx` option for `charter` fonts in math.  Using the package call

```
\usepackage[varg,charter]{newtxmath}
```

the previous example becomes

[image]

which produces a `\nu` that is closer to the OP's requested glyph.

Comment: The `charter` font option gives a `nu` somewhat close to the requested shape that could be useful.

Comment: @Cicada -- That's a good suggestion. I've edited my answer to incorporate your idea.