# PDFLaTeX: changing the font type of the Greek mathematical symbols in formula

Tags: math-mode, fonts, greek

Which options do I have to modify the font that PDFLaTeX used to typeset Greek letters in mathematical formulas?

For example:

> \textgreek{mvopr} is `textgreek' and $\mu\nu\omicron\pi\rho$ is a formula

gives

[image]

I do not like the standard rendering of Greek symbols too much. Please note I am not interested in

- matching the particular font of `textgreek`, but in picking from a selection if one exists;
- changing the whole set of fonts, like in [how to select math font in document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30049/how-to-select-math-font-in-document);
- packages that PDFLaTex does not (seem to) process (easily), like in [Greek symbol fonts in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508231/greek-symbol-fonts-in-latex).

Happy to be corrected and provide additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any math font package and its options (such as `slantedgreek`).  The `isomath` package allows you to select any OML-encoded math font as one of your math alphabets, or you can use the LaTeX kernel’s `\DeclareMathAlphabet` for this.  The `isomath` manual has a reasonably-comprehensive list of available fonts that support OML.

Additionally, `mathastext` allows you to select any LGR-encoded 8-bit font as your Greek math alphabet, with any math version.  Check out the [LaTeX Font Catalogue.](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/)

It’s more work, but there are tools to re-encode any TrueType or OpenType font into legacy 8-bit TeX encodings usable with PDFTeX.

#### Examples

This MWE uses GFS Porson as the Greek math font.  From roughly the 1920s to the 1960s, Porson was a common Greek companion font to Monotype Modern, on which DEK based Computer Modern.  You’ll notice how similar the shapes are to the default TeX Greek symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[LGRgreek, italic]{mathastext}

\MTgreekfont{porson}
\Mathastext
% Can also declare \MTgreekfont for each \MTDeclareVersion

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\[ (x, y, z) \to ( \rho, \phi, \theta ) \]
\end{document}
```

[image: GFS Porson + Latin Modern sample]

The following is an extremely-contrived example of defining an upright bold-sans-serif math version, to match the formatting of a section header, using GFS Complutum as the matching math font.  (If you are ever stuck trying to do this in PDFTeX, you might try Arev, a heavy sans-serif font that comes in OML.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[LGRgreek,subdued]{mathastext}

\MTgreekfont{complutum}
\MTDeclareVersion[n]{sansbold}{T1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\Mathastextversion{sansbold}
\section{\normalfont\fontfamily{cmbr}\bfseries\selectfont%
  From \(x\) and \(y\) to \(\theta\) and \(\phi\)%
}
\Mathastextversion{normal}

We can map \( (x,y,z) \to (\rho,\theta,\phi) \).
\end{document}
```

[image: CM Bright + GFS Complutum sample]

Comment: Thanks, intriguing. A follow-up question is: where did you pick up the porson font family for example? If I look for it in the LaTeX font catalogue (type `porson site:https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/` in your browser search box) I cannot find anything. In other words, at this point I would like to choose my favourite Greek font. Where can I get to know their names and preview them?

Comment: @XavierStuvw You can check out [the `font-greek` category on CTAN.](https://ctan.org/topic/font-greek)  You can also search your TeX installation for files that match the pattern `lgr*.fd` and `oml*.fd`.