# Use \prec from AMS

Tags: amsmath, classicthesis, amssymb, mathabx

My math font is `mathabx`. I love this font, but I have to use `<` and `\prec`, and both symbols are so similar in this font.

Therefore, I'm trying to use `\prec` from `cmr` (AMS symbol) to make it different. I read about `\DeclareMathSymbol`, but I don't know how to get the `\prec` code.

Thanks!

Comment: The default math font for classithesis is not mathabx. Can you please show a minimal example of code?

Comment: Ok! Sorry, i didn't realize that i comes include with the template. So, I'm using `mathabx`but the simbols `\prec`and `<` looks so similar there. My problem is that I want to keep this font for every symbol but keep \prec from the AMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redeclare the symbols to use Computer Modern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\succ}{\mathrel}{cmsymbols}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\prec}{\mathrel}{cmsymbols}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\succeq}{\mathrel}{cmsymbols}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\preceq}{\mathrel}{cmsymbols}{"16}

\begin{document}

$<\prec>\succ\le\preceq\ge\succeq$

\end{document}
```

[image]