# What math fonts are available that work in xelatex?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, mathspec

For LaTeX, we have the [Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) which is a good resource for fonts available through LaTeX.

There doesn't appear to be a similar resource for Xe(La)TeX. So let's say I'm bored of computer modern and I want to try out some new fonts in XeLaTeX. Where can I find out what's available? Ideally I'd like to find what fonts have a math alphabet, at least some common ligatures (ff, ffi etc) and old style figures…

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With upcoming TeXLive 2017:

```
Latin Modern Math 
TeX Gyre Pagella Math
TeX Gyre Bonum Math
TeX Gyre Termes Math
TeX Gyre Schola Math
Libertinus Math
XITS Math
STIX Math 
Asana Math
DejaVu Math
```

from https://sourceforge.net/projects/stixfonts/?source=typ_redirect

```
STIX Two Text and Math
```

from http://tug.org/lucida

```
Lucida New Math  (Type 1)
Lucida Bright Math OT
```

from https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf

```
Neo-Euler math
```

from http://www.typoma.com

```
Minion Math
```

from Microsoft

```
Cambria Math
```

and of course `Computer Modern`

Comment: also [Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf)

Comment: Lucida OpenType fonts (including Lucida Math) have been released today and area available from the TUG store: http://www.tug.org/store/lucida/  They are not free, but available at very reasonable prices (compared to other fonts). In addition, members of several TeX users groups can get a discount.

Comment: @Herbert: Neo Euler is not on CTAN, but you can get it from GitHub: https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf

Comment: I just saw that there's a couple of articles on this in the latest TUGboat.

Comment: There is also Minion Math (non-free, and pricey) from typoma GmbH.

Comment: there are some more commercial math fonts ...

Comment: There is now also _TeX Gyre Schola Math_ and _Tex Gyre Bonum Math_.

Comment: yes, but they are not complete by now!

Comment: Is it better to use TeX-Gyre Pagella Math or NewPX or Asana?.  I'm looking for some opentype font with nice math, and with text looking like Palatino (because of university restrictions).

Comment: TeX-Gyre Pagella Math is a good choice together with TeX Gyre Pagella

Comment: In addition to STIX Math, there's now STIX Two Math. Much better than both STIX Math and XITS Math.

Comment: @Mico: but not on TeXLive, right?

Comment: You're right! The STIX Two font files are not yet on TeXLive, and they're not even on the CTAN. No idea why they're still only available from https://sourceforge.net/projects/stixfonts/. It's a shame, really, as STIX Two is much better than STIX (which *is* on the CTAN and part of TeXlive).

Comment: @Mico they seem to be available now, packages for Type1 and OTF STIX2 fonts: https://ctan.org/pkg/stix2-type1, https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/stix2-otf

Comment: @JorgeGT - Thanks! That's most welcome news.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2018/03/07 a new font `GFS Neohellenic Math` is on CTAN. It is accompanied by a text font released earlier.

This is a sans font, which, according to a few tests, supports different math styles.

Due to the fact that TeXLive is now (2018/03/09) frozen, the font is available for MikTeX or here: https://ctan.org/pkg/gfsneohellenicmath (otf file is inside zip archive).