# Why do some fonts work and others don't in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I use the Helvetica font and everything is OK, but if I try to use Garamond for instance then I run into problems... and I cannot compile (or the pdf tells me that it cannot retrieve the fonts, when I try for instance to use bt-charter).. I use the following packages in my tex file and I compite with xelatex (because of strange characters in my bib file). Is the problem coming from here?

```
\documentclass[12pt,captions=nooneline]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.2in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}



\usepackage{helvet}

\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim}
```

Comment: Don't use inputenx or inputenc with xelatex. Beside this: try to make your question more concrete by concentrating on one problem and make a complete but minimal example for this problem.

Comment: in addition to what Ulrike and Alan said: you're not telling us which of the many fonts called Garamond you're using and how you're invoking it. »if I try to use garamond for instance then I run into problems« is a rather vague description of the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately you are doing many things wrong all at the same time. First of all, with XeTeX should should never load the `inputenc` package; XeTeX deals with UTF-8 encoded files automatically.

See [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/2693)

Furthermore, if the reason for switching to XeTeX is properties of your `.bib` file, then you should not be using the `harvard` package and `bibtex` at all, but you must use `biblatex` and `biber`, since `bibtex` cannot deal with a UTF-8 encoded `.bib` file.

That being said, however, depending on how you are managing your `.bib` file, your reference manager may allow you to input UTF-8 characters but actually converts them to non-UTF-8 equivalents, in which case you may not require `bibilatex` and `biber`.

See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693)

On the font issue you need to be more explicit in what the problem is. If you are using XeTeX you usually load system fonts by name using the `fontspec` package. But to see exactly what the problem is,  you should make a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/2693) which consists of a complete document (with `\documentclass{}` ... `\begin{document}`  ... `\end{document}` and *just* the packages that give rise to the problem. Then ask your question around that.

For example, for math fonts that are compatible with XeTeX see:

[What math fonts are available that work in xelatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43813/2693)

But first it seems you need to do a bit more general reading about the way all of the pieces of TeX and LaTeX work together.

See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693)