# XeTeX: better using system fonts or packages?

Tags: fonts, xetex, packages, best-practices, libertine

I've recently switched to XeTeX. 
In my document I use this code to set the fonts:

```
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
```

I installed Libertine and biolinium from the ubuntu repositories and I downloaded XITS and installed in my `.fonts` directory... Now I'd like to know what are the main differences between my approach and using the real latex packages (like `libertineotf`.)

Comment: Why don't you use the mono font from Libertine?

Comment: The idea came from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/what-best-combination-of-fonts-for-serif-sans-and-mono-do-you-recommend), but actually I don't use mono fonts that much

Comment: I guess using the package is seen as a simpler straightforward solution for some users, but, de facto, using one or the other of these won't change the final result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local fonts reduce the portability of the source code

compiling on computers without access to those fonts.

This should not effect any output files, to the final viewing.