# Showcase of fonts that looks great together

Tags: fonts, typography, big-list

There is LaTeX font catalogue available [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

But there only the list of fonts, no comparison and recommendation of fonts, to use together.

The list of fonts pairs: for text (many sans fonts have serif version and vice verse) and for math, - (or triples, with monospace one) would be great.

Comment: what exactly is your question? More like "has someone ever compiled a survey of typefaces they think look great together?", or more like "why not, as a community effort, here on TeX.SE, create a big list of typefaces that we think look great together?". But even if that part was clear, "looking great together" is a highly subjective and context-dependent matter, so that'll be a different problem altogehter...

Comment: Some people have compared how to blend text and math typefaces: http//tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf‎.

Comment: PS: have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/what-best-combination-of-fonts-for-serif-sans-and-mono-do-you-recommend?rq=1 ?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen’s link for the lazy: http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf

Comment: @MarcvanDongen You are missing the `:` between `http` and `//`, that’s all. Otherwise, the syntax `[URL text](URL)` should have worked, too.