# Dealing with matrices with large symbolic expressions

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I have been trying to express my matrices in a clear way. The problem I have is that the symbolic terms inside the matrices are sometime large and this kind of disturbs the ***matrix look*** of the matrix. I mean

```
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y
\end{pmatrix}
```

looks like how a matrix should. But if you have an expression there, like

```
\begin{pmatrix}
x + y cos(\theta) & y + x sin(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
```

the matrix resembles less like a *2X1* matrix and more like two terms with a little space in between and surrounded by brackets. Is there a better command that makes matrices with reasonably large terms appear '*normal*'. I can imagine my question maybe a bit unclear.

Edit: Maybe a better font for math dominated text would be better for representation? Suggestions?

Comment: bmatrix with `|` in the middle ? Inline matrices are always strange to read anyways

Comment: I like pmatrix in general...and it would be hard for me to change the expression everywhere now...anyways what do you mean with | in the middle? Can you give me the syntax to try out?

Comment: `(\begin{array}{c|c} .... \end{array})`

Comment: hahaha...its actually a | in the middle :D...sorry but it looks a bit weird in midst of all these equations ;)

Comment: well better than double parentheses for me

Comment: Well it would be trivially easy to add a little bit more space between them if that's the issue `\begin{pmatrix}
x + y cos(\theta) & & y + x sin(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}` but I would think it should be obvious from the context what's going on. *x* x 1 matrices -- especially 2 x 1 matrices, always looked  a bit weird to me.

Comment: Or you could switch out `pmatrix` for `bmatrix`. Matrices with square brackets always looked a bit more matrix-y to me, maybe because I'm used to them, but given the usual order of brackets is {[( ... )]} a 2 x 1 matrix with square brackets might look more like a matrix and less immediately like something in parentheses

Comment: Oh and `\sin` and `\cos` is an absolute **must**

Comment: @Au101 thanks for /sin /cos thing...funny I didn't know...and you are right about x x 1 matrrices...I would switch to bmatrix if I can't find any other solution, even though it would a cumbersome task for me

Comment: @Zero `\sin` sir/madam, not `/sin`. Shouldn't be very difficult, find and replace. replace `\begin{pmatrix}` with `\begin{bmatrix}`. Same for `\end`

Comment: @Au101 I feel stupid now...anyways do you have a better font for a thesis with a lot of mathematical expressions?

Comment: @Zero No need to feel stupid. Better to ask new questions as new questions, rather than in the comments, but I think font requests would probably not be considered on-topic as it's really a matter of opinion, but personally I would be very unlikely to turn my back on my beloved Computer Modern (the default). Maybe you might like this Q&A http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/what-best-combination-of-fonts-for-serif-sans-and-mono-do-you-recommend

Comment: @Au101 thanks...I really do not like how the bmatrix looks...maybe I would experiment with the fonts...thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Zero - If you're thinking about using a font family other than `Computer Modern`, you may want to take a look at the posting [Suggest a “nice” font family for my basic LaTeX template (text and math)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59702/5001).

Answer (score 3):

I see nothing wrong with the usual typesetting: the large space between entries is sufficient. I probably would use `bmatrix` anyway.

You can see whether the following trick is what you need: we reduce the space around binary operation symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox{\rpmatrixbox}
\newenvironment{rpmatrix}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\rpmatrixbox}
  \setlength{\medmuskip}{.5\medmuskip}%
  $\begin{pmatrix}}
 {\end{pmatrix}$\end{lrbox}\usebox\rpmatrixbox}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pmatrix} x+y\cos(\theta) & y+x\sin(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$

\medskip

$\begin{rpmatrix} x+y\cos(\theta) & y+x\sin(\theta)\end{rpmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I'd be tempted to omit the parentheses around `\theta`, i.e., I'd write `\cos\theta` and `\sin\theta`. That way, there are no parentheses in the interior of the `pmatrix` environments to compete visually with the parentheses that enclose the environments.

Comment: @Mico I too prefer not having them if the argument is a variable or of the form “number times variable”.